# AMQP redelivery policy

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, amqp

I'm using Apache Camel AMQP Component with Azure Service Bus. I want to add a redelivery policy as it's possible to do for ActiveMQ:

```java
private void addRedeliveryPolicy(ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory) {
    RedeliveryPolicy policy = factory.getRedeliveryPolicy();
    policy.setMaximumRedeliveries(5);
    policy.setMaximumRedeliveryDelay(10000);
    policy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(10);
    policy.setRedeliveryDelay(30);
}
```

In a case of AMQPComponent in redelivery policy exists single getter:

```java
private void addRedeliveryPolicy(JmsConnectionFactory factory) {
    JmsRedeliveryPolicy defaultCallbackRedeliveryPolicy = factory.getRedeliveryPolicy();
    factory.getRedeliveryPolicy().getMaxRedeliveries(...);
}
```

Using standard AMQP and Qpid libraries. Question - how to set the redelivery features as: redeliveryDalay, redeliveryAttempts, for the AMQP component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AMQP JMS client does not support that same configuration options as the Openwire JMS client.  The primary reason for this is that unlike the Openwire client redelivery does not happen locally on the AMQP JMS client but instead the message are released back to the broker for redispatch.  This means that any delay processing or other mechanics would need to be done at the broker side not on the client.

The only option currently in the client is a max redelivery options which is applied based on the AMQP delivery count that is tracked as part of the message transfer.

Comment: From my understanding on ActiveMQ broker(OpenwireJMS) redelivery not happening locally on client. When on transacted consumer message should be redelivered, its returning back to queue(broker) with mark - redeliveryActivated. Then consuming again by redeliveryPolicy

Comment: As one of the developers of the ActiveMQ broker I can say your understanding is flawed.  Client redelivery is local until the maxRedeliveries value is reached and then the message is returned via PoisonAck and then broker redelivery kicks in

Answer (score 2):

Camel's ActiveMQ component uses the OpenWire JMS client implementation which is specific to ActiveMQ. It uses the OpenWire protocol which is not standardized. It implements particular client-side based redelivery features configured via its `RedeliveryPolicy` object.

Camel's AMQP component uses the Qpid AMQP client which can interoperate with any AMQP broker, client, router, etc. and must adhere to the AMQP specification. It has an *interface* (i.e. `JmsRedeliveryPolicy`) that you apparently must implement to configure redelivery. See [this example](https://github.com/apache/qpid-jms/blob/afcf6ab049aaac9bc818197c406e936ed6cc1206/qpid-jms-client/src/test/java/org/apache/qpid/jms/integration/ConnectionFactoryIntegrationTest.java#L604). Once your policy is implemented just invoke `setRedeliveryPolicy()` on your `JmsConnectionFactory`.

The main point to remember here is that the two implementations are 100% independent so what you can configure on one is not going to necessarily be available on the other. Currently the ActiveMQ 5.x `RedeliveryPolicy` has many more options than the Qpid `JmsRedeliveryPolicy`.

Keep in mind that in many (if not most) cases complex redelivery semantics can be configured on the *broker* so if there are configuration elements you want which are not available on Qpid's `JmsRedeliveryPolicy` I recommend you look at whatever broker you're using as you may find equivalent options there.

Comment: @jbertram, do you have suggestions how to configure JmsRedeliveryPolicy with redeliveryDalays, attempts etc?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comments.

Comment: @jbertram, thank you. In other words answer to my quiestion is: its impossible.